# CAKEPHP Adding element to home page takes incorrect URL

Tags: cakephp

I have a POST model and a COMMENT model. In my Comments element i am retrieving POST_ID from URL which is working fine.

Now i am calling POST and COMMENT element on homepage but when i add comment it is not taking the id from URL as the URL is now /home rather than /post/view/id.

How can i sort this out?

This is how i am retrieving Id from URL

```
$id = $this->request['pass'][0];
echo $this->form->input('note_id', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$id));
```

Comment: What's your goal here? Why do you need to know what page it came from (which you could get with `$this->referer()`)? What do you use the id for? Please explain the problem.

Comment: What i want is that all the posts should appear on the main page with the comments made on them by different users as on facebook. Right now when i open a single post and comment on it, the comment view takes the id of the post from the URL and save the id in POST_ID field of the comment table. Now when i display both the POSTS and COMMENTS on the home page and try to comment below a single post it takes HOME in $ID variable instead of the ID of the POST.

Comment: That makes sense, because `home` is the first passed argument. What would you like it to store as the id, if not 'home'?

Comment: I am already storing POST_ID from post/view/id in COMMENTS table field post_id but when i call the POST and COMMENT view in home page i want comment to take post_id rather than home ... How would i do that?

Comment: What would the post id be on the home page? If no ID is passed, I'm not sure what you expect. You're viewing the home page.. not a post. The home page doesn't have an ID, so what would you save in POST_ID?

Comment: Ok let me be more clear here now...

I have two elements one for Posts and other for Comments ... When i view the posts via posts/view/id, the Comment element works fine.

Now what i want is that it should be similar to Facebook wall, so for that i tried to call both the elements on home page. Is there any way i can retrieve the POST_ID for Comments table on the home page? If not, then how can comments work on the home page? Any other way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are displaying the post and comment you probably have arrays like `$posts['Post']` and `$comments['Comment']` so for getting post_id you can probably use `$posts['Post']['id']`

the id you can set then

```php
echo $this->form->input('note_id', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$posts['Post']['id']));
```